# Mobizen Screen Recording, What type method they are using for their floating bubble

Tags: android, android-studio, android-screen-support, android-screen

Mobizen Screen Recording. What type method they are using for their floating bubble? Is it a service because you can not call

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { ... }
```

This function in service? What exactly does Mobizen screen recorder for Android is using?